# Categorisation and subtotal in excel

Tags: excel

So, I have a table of data (transactions), and I'd like to calculate sub-totals for different categories (Ents, Travel, Groceries etc.)

I'm using

```
=SUMIFS(F1:F20, H1:H20, "Ents")
```

to calculate the sub-total of each category. Column F is the amount of the transaction (£), Column H lists the categoies, where "Ents" is an example. The above creates the sub-total for the "Ents" category.

What I'd like to do is **restrict** this sub-total to a certain time frame. IE: For all transactions in a given month.

Column A contains the Date of the transaction.

Ultimately, I'd like to draw these category sub-totals into a seperate table for a monthly financial overview.

While I'm aware that a pivot table would enable all sorts of functionality, I'd prefer to keep things simple - I'm sure that there will be some sort of selector that can be added to the formula, but my google-fu is failing me.

Please can someone give me the final piece of formula puzzle?

Cheers!

Comment: What column has the dates?

Comment: Pivot Tables are designed for things like this. If you don't already know about them, a small amount of time spent learning about them would pay off sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column A has dates in it then you can add that into your SumIFS condition to get the total by daterange. 
Eg: Below gives sum of Dec15 .

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,">="&"01/12/2015",A:A,"<="&"31/12/2015",H:H,"=Ents")
```